# Limit max upload file size in front end submmission form

Tags: uploads

I'm a WordPress beginner and I'm working on a travel directory that user can register and have a front end control panel and  have a front end submission form where user  can add property description and of course images .

I have a multi site installation but upload settings do not work for front end(max upload file size and file type). I suppose I can use a filter but I could not find something that works for front end... tried several plugins , all work in back end.

Actually I need a step by step help or on line guide I could not find yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have some ways to do that:

In your **functions.php** or **wp-config.php**

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '15M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '15M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

In your **.htaccess** (if you use apache2)

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 15M
php_value post_max_size 15M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

If you use **nginx**

```
http {
  client_max_body_size 15m;
}
```

In your **php.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize = 15M
post_max_size = 15M
max_execution_time = 300
```

They all work, so you can choose what best suits you, the size is set in MB so all the examples above will set the max upload to **15MB**.

Comment: I need to limit max upload for each Image at 200kb, restricte file type upload (only jpg/png and set a minimum Image size ...let' say 900x 400 px

Comment: Can you post the code of the form, and the function that receives the request when the form is submited?

Comment: how to add code...i tried but looks weird and does not show correct.

Comment: Can you post what you did?

Comment: I will try again

Comment: added php code submit images template

Comment: which code of my answer you tried, how you did it and what happened?

Comment: i did not try nothing, just added form php code

Comment: So try one of the codes above, depending on your setup.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
global $action;
global $edit_id;
global $embed_video_id;
global $option_video;
global $edit_link_details;
$images='';
$thumbid='';
$attachid='';
$arguments = array(
  'numberposts'     => -1,
  'post_type'       => 'attachment',
  'post_parent'     => $edit_id,
  'post_status'     => null,
  'exclude'         => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
  'orderby'         => 'menu_order',
  'order'           => 'ASC'
 );
 $post_attachments = get_posts($arguments);
 $post_thumbnail_id = $thumbid = get_post_thumbnail_id( $edit_id );


foreach ($post_attachments as $attachment) {
    $preview =  wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID,                    'wpestate_property_listings');    

    if($preview[0]!=''){
        $images .=  '<div class="uploaded_images"                                      data-imageid="'.$attachment->ID.'"><img src="'.$preview[0].'" alt="thumb"          /><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>';
        if($post_thumbnail_id == $attachment->ID){
            $images .='<i class="fa thumber fa-star"></i>';
        }
    }else{
        $images .=  '<div class="uploaded_images" data-imageid="'.$attachment->ID.'"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/img/pdf.png" alt="thumb" /><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>';
        if($post_thumbnail_id == $attachment->ID){
            $images .='<i class="fa thumber fa-star"></i>';
        }
    }


    $images .='</div>';
    $attachid.= ','.$attachment->ID;
    }


   ?>


<div class="col-md-12" id="new_post2">
<div class="user_dashboard_panel">
<h4 class="user_dashboard_panel_title"><?php  esc_html_e('Listing           Media','wpestate');?></h4>



<div class="col-md-12" id="profile_message"></div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="upload-container">                 
        <div id="aaiu-upload-container">                 
            <div id="aaiu-upload-imagelist">
                <ul id="aaiu-ul-list" class="aaiu-upload-list"></ul>
            </div>

            <div id="imagelist">
            <?php 
                if($images!=''){
                    print $images;
                }
            ?>  
            </div>

            <div id="aaiu-uploader"  class=" wpb_btn-small wpestate_vc_button  vc_button"><?php esc_html_e('Select Media','wpestate');?></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="attachid" id="attachid" value="<?php echo $attachid;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="attachthumb" id="attachthumb" value="<?php echo $thumbid;?>">
            <p class="full_form full_form_image">
                <?php esc_html_e('*Double Click on the image to select featured. ','wpestate');?></br>
                 <?php esc_html_e('**Change images order with Drag & Drop. ','wpestate');?>
            </p>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <p>
        <label for="embed_video_type"><?php esc_html_e('Video from','wpestate');?></label>
        <select id="embed_video_type" name="embed_video_type" class="select-submit2">
            <?php print $option_video;?>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
    <p>     
       <label for="embed_video_id"><?php esc_html_e('Video id: ','wpestate');?></label>
       <input type="text" id="embed_video_id" class="form-control"  name="embed_video_id" size="40" value="<?php print $embed_video_id;?>">
    </p>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-12" style="display: inline-block;"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="" id="listing_edit" value="<?php echo  $edit_id;?>">
    <input type="submit" class="wpb_btn-info wpb_btn-small wpestate_vc_button  vc_button" id="edit_prop_image" value="<?php esc_html_e('Save', 'wpestate') ?>" />
    <a href="<?php echo  $edit_link_details;?>" class="next_submit_page"><?php esc_html_e('Go to Details settings (*make sure you click save first).','wpestate');?></a>

 </div>

 </div>
```